# @PostConstruct and @Schedule with cron

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduling

I was using the following code-snippet for a long time to trigger an export right after the application was run and as well at the provided crontab.

```java
@PostConstruct
@Scheduled(cron = "${" + EXPORT_SCHEDULE + "}")
public void exportJob()
{
    exportService().exportTask();
}
```

After updating to Spring-Boot 2.6.x the policy according to "cyclic bean definition" got stricter and I couldn't use both annotations on this method anymore. Some answers recommended merging the @PostConstruct into the @Scheduled as `initialDelay = 0` but crontab and the other properties of @Scheduled are not compatible. Resulting in following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'exportJob': 'initialDelay' not supported for cron triggers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution may be to implement a [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) bean.  This interface contains a `run()` method that is executed after the application startup

```java
@Bean
CommandLineRunner cronJobRunner(CronJobService cronJobService) {
  return args ->  cronJobService.cronJob();
}
```

Comment: It does work well and it is almost as concise as @PostConstruct.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution I found was to use just the @Scheduled annotation but also have another method be annotated with @Scheduled and `initialDelay=0` which just proxies the other method.

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "${" + EXPORT_SCHEDULE + "}")
public void cronJob()
{
    exportService().exportTask();
}

@Scheduled(fixedRate = Integer.MAX_VALUE, initialDelay = 0)
public void exportJob()
{
    cronJob();
}
```

In theory, the cronJob is triggered more often, hence I chose it to do the service call. One could structure the call chain in the opposite direction as well.